# Chrome does not cache images and css

Tags: google-chrome, flask, browser-cache

I have a Flask web app and it appears that Chrome will not cache the images and css and instead request them from the server every time (see screenshots)

Is this normal or should the browser be caching these and i am doing something wrong?

[Screenshots from developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aplEB.png)

Answer (score 2):

Can you please check settings in your developer console. It has setting "disable cache (while DevTools is open)"
[image]

If this setting enabled, Chrome everytime will download assets and ignore Cache-Control header

Comment: Hi Victor, My the disable cache setting is unchecked for me. Could this be because i am using the flask debug mode and not an actual server like apache?

Comment: For anyone still interested in this, it appears that the reason the browser was not caching was because i was using flask and serving from the local server. Once i deployed on an Apache server, caching started to work properly.

Comment: Hi ThierryMichel, I'm using gunicorn on Google App Engine and the cache is not loading for anything static pulled up with "url_for(..)". It's "only" a few hundred ms, but it is still annoying. Were you ever able to find a setting to force caching?